# How do I suggest broken link fixes to a Drupal module project page description?

Tags: community-official-site

I noticed that a Drupal module's project page description has a broken link.

How do I suggest/contribute the change? Is this done through GIT?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to report documentation bug, because project page is maintained by module maintainers, and it's entry point to all other documentation.

1. You need to log in
2. Go to the module page
3. In the right sidebar, you will have section "Issues for [module name]"
4. Enter issue queue by clicking any link in this section, for example open bugs.
5. On the page "Issues for [module name]", click "Create a new issue"
6. Set the Component field to "Documentation" (unless maintainers defined better fitting component option for your purpose)
7. Fill all the rest as needed

Comment: This is the correct answer. The project page are edited from the project maintainer and co-maintainers. If there is anything wrong in the project page, a issue should be opened in the project queue.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems like a variation of something I recently ran into when I was looking for the "official" documentation of the [Raty](https://www.drupal.org/project/raty) module, which you can find via the "[Read documentation](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/)" link on its project page. Here is some more info about this module:

> ... Raty is designed to be an immediate, zero-config option to either display stars from any numeric field or use them as field input widgets.

Trying to get started with this docu is not obvious. That's why I went for a plan-b ... I decided to try to contribute some brand new [Community documentation about the Raty module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2507547). It's still a kind of "work in progress", but I'd hope it'll be considered as a "best possible alternative available today". Anybody interested in contributing to it also: be my guest and go ahead to also contribute to it.

I also created an issue for Raty, i.e. [Complete community docu for the Raty module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2507589). So now it's a matter of waiting for the (co-) maintainers to yes/no consider the issue I created (though the Community documentation page is already there, be it that it isn't obvious yet to make people aware of that).

Comment: If the link is merely broken, but the content exist, or there are indications it existed, creating new page is pointless, or even harmful.

Comment: @Mołot : I see your viewpoint, but I think it's more like "it depends". As a sample, and if you want, in "my" docu case about the Raty module. if you were to "get started" with that module (first time you want to use it), would you prefer to start from the (current) "Read documentation" link, or rather the new community docu page I created? Understand "my" viewpoint?

Comment: Yes, I just don't quite agree. I think it's better to cooperate than to make new things and then argue whose is better.

Comment: @Mołot: referring to that Raty module and "coorporate", my "point" (+ issue I created today) is exactly about that. The current implementation of that "read docu", is a link to an URL that the Drupal "community" cannot edit / contribute to. With the Community page I created, anybody who's interested can start "coorporating" / "contributing" about producing docu for the Raty module. if you want, checkout what has started to happen with the community docu of modules such as 'chart' or 'charts', even some "novices" have contributed already, which I really like ...